# Understanding of "Somewhat Surprising" First Order Logic Expression in E.J.Lemmon, Beginning Logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In "Beginning Logic" by E.J.Lemmon, Page 126, Theorem 118 (1994 Reprint) a "somewhat surprising" inter-derivability result in Predicate Calculus is proved:
$$( (\exists x\, Hx) \implies P)  \dashv \vdash \forall x\, (Hx \implies P) $$

where Hx is a one place predicate and P is a zero place predicate.

My question relates to the left to right meaning of the $( (\exists x\, Hx) \implies P) \vdash \forall x\, (Hx \implies P) $ derivation (presumably that is the 'somewhat surprising' direction), in the context of a truth table meaning of "$\implies$".

If the  $((\exists x\, Hx) \implies P)$ expression is to mean (when it is true)  "if there is an element $t$ in the domain with $Hx[x\backslash t]$ true" then $P$ can only be true - because $P$ can't be false due to the truth table meaning of "$\implies$". This expression does not appear to talk about any specific element $f$ in the domain where $Hx[x\backslash f]$ is false.

However if in addition to $t$ there is an element $f$ in the domain where the expression $Hx[x\backslash f]$ is false then $\forall x (Hx \implies P)$ at this location gives, using $(Hx \implies P)[x\backslash f]$, the truth interpretation "$\bot \implies P$". This would mean at the location $f$, $P$ can be false whilst still giving $(Hx \implies P)[x\backslash f]$ true. So the $(Hx \implies P)$ expression (when true) could give two possible truth values for $P$ - at $f$ it could give $P$ is false and applying the same method at $t$, it gives $P$ is true. This would suggest a contradiction occurs and also that the two sides of the derivation don't actually say the same thing.

Any help to correct my understanding of how to apply the truth interpretation of "$\implies$" in the above will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $P$ is a $0$-place predicate, so it's either always true or always false for the entire model.  The point is that the only way for $\Rightarrow$ to fail is for the premise to be true while the consequence is false.

Comment: $\vdash$ is about derivability in the predicate calculus: thus, you have to provide  a derivation.

Comment: We can reason about $\vDash$ : assume for contardiction that the premise is TRUE while the conclusion is FALSE. The last means that for some $x$ - call it $a$ - we have that the conditional is FALSE, i.e. $Ha \to P$ is FALSE. This implies : $Ha$ TRUE and $P$ FALSE. But if $P$ is FALSE, how can $(\exists x Hx) \to P$ be TRUE ?

Comment: There is only one possibility : $(\exists x Hx)$ FALSE. But we know that $Ha$ is TRUE: CONTRADICTION !

Comment: @Robert and Mauro - thanks for your kind help. I now see the question is missing that : surprisingly (to me!) in a “For All  x (Hx -> P)” expression then even if there is only one element t with Hx[x\t] true, then P has to be true. Even if there is an element f with Hx[x/f] false, though this f element case could lead to P being either true or false at the element f, the P is false case is excluded by the sole element with Hx[x\t] -> P, since P cant be false at the element t [as (Hx[x\t] -> P) has to be true since overall its a true “For All  x (Hx -> P)” and P is the same everywhere].

Comment: An explanation to the dual of this equilvalence, $\exists x(Ax \implies B)$ and $(\forall x Ax) \implies B$, can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188924/344246

Comment: @ lemontree - nice link, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is about inter-*deriability*, $\dashv \vdash$. This is a purely syntactic notion. You can convince yourself of the truth of this statement by a corresponding pair of derivations:

1. $\exists x Hx \to P \vdash \forall x (Hx \to P)$:
   [image]
2. $\forall x (Hx \to P) \vdash \exists x Hx \to P$:

[image]

3. derivation $\mathcal{D}$ for the transitions $\neg (Ha \to P) \vdash Ha \land \neg P$ and $\neg(\exists x \to P) \vdash \exists x Hx \land \neg P$: 
   [image]

So $\exists x Hx \to P \vdash \forall x (Hx \to P)$ and $\forall x (Hx \to P) \vdash \exists x Hx \to P$, therefore $\exists x Hx \to P \vdash \vdash \forall x (Hx \to P)$. This proves the theorem you stated, namely $\vdash$.

Since you seem to be also/more interested in a semantic argument, namely $\vDash$, and due to soundness and completeness, we luckily also have $\exists x Hx \to P \vDash \forall x (Hx \to P)$, let's explain what happens in the formal proof; this will also explain what's going on in the semantics:

We prove both directions by contradition, i.e. we first assume that the derivation/entailment doesn't hold, which means that the premise is true while the conclusion is not, and derive a contradiction, from which we can deduce that the derivability/entailment does hold.

1. $\exists x Hx \to P \vdash, \vDash \forall x (Hx \to P)$:
   Assume $\exists x Hx \to P$ but $\neg \forall x (Hx \to P)$ (l. 1-2). This means that there is some object, say $a$, such that $\neg (Ha \to P)$ (l. 2-6), and if the implication is false, then it must be the case that $Ha$ but $\neg P$ (l. 7-10). Since we found an object $a$ such that $Ha$, we know that there exists an $x$ s.t. $Hx$, i.e. $\exists x Hx$ (l. 11). But modus ponens with the premise $\exists Hx \to P$ tells us that then $P$ must hold, which contradicts the statement $\neg P$ (l. 12-13) which we derived from the assumption that $Hx \to P$ does not hold of $a$. Since assuming $\neg \forall x (Hx \to P)$ leads to a contradiction, the negation of the statement must have been false (l. 14), and it follows that $\exists x Hx \to P \vDash \forall x(Hx \to P)$ (l. 15), which completes the proof of one direction.
2. $\forall x (Hx \to P) \vdash, \vDash \exists x Hx \to P$:
   Again, we prove by contradiction and assume that $\forall x(Hx \to P)$, but $\neg (\exists x \to P)$ (l. 1-2). Again, this is equivalent to stating that $\exists x$ and $\neg P$ holds (l. 2-6), so there is an $x$ to which $H$ applies but $P$ is not true. Let's call this element $a$ (l. 7). From the assumption $\forall x(Hx \to P)$ it follows that this must also hold of our $a$, so by modus ponens we get $P$ (l. 8-9). But this again contradicts the statement $\neg P$ which we derived from our assumption $\neg (\exists x \to P)$ (l. 10). So this assumption must have been false (l. 11), and we have $\exists x Hx \to P$ (l. 12) derived from $\forall x (Hx \to P)$, which proves the other direction.
3. is just the missing piece in the derivations 1. and 2. which I sourced out so the proofs wouldn't get too huge.

Comment: good thorough proofs, thanks. Also is (∃xHx)→P is equivalent to (∃xHx)→∃xP which is equivalent to  ∃x(Hx→P) [I was wondering if you would have a reference - including for your proofs?] and for ∀x ? I'm also guessing P  ⊢ ∃xP  and ∃xP ⊢  P ? Intriguingly ∃x(Ax⟹B) ⊢ (∀xAx)⟹B is the non intuitive direction for the modified form (to me!), though the semantic demonstration for this modified form of the question doesn't depend on what ∀x does this time, its a straight truth table of False ⟹B when the 'usual case of ∀xAx is false' arises even when ∃xAx is true for some elements' ?

Comment: In the special case where, as in your example, $P$ is a zero-place predicate and contains no free variables, prepending quantification won't do anything, so in that case $(\exists x Hx) \to P$ is equivalent to $(\exists x Hx) \to (\exists x P)$. However, this is *not* equvalent to $\exists x(Hx \to P)$, but only to $\exists x (\exists x Hx \to P)$ (you can move the second $\exists$ in front of the implication, but the other $\exists$ remains - but note that the moved-out $\exists$ still won't have any effect, because the innermost $\exists$ will "overwrite" the binding.

Comment: $P \vdash \exists x P$ and $\exists P \vdash P$: Again, $\vdash$ is derivability in some formal system, wheres your thoughts were on $\vDash$; in any case, both $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ will only work with the restriction that $P$ is a zero-place predicate that does not not contain free occurrences of $x$, so these inferences are not valid for abitrary formulas $P$.

Comment: The proofs (derivations and argumentations) I set up by myself, so no references. The last part of your question I don't understand, sorry. You need to rephrase.

Comment: wow - proofs russled up in a jiffy - neat. The last part rephrased is : In ∃x(Ax⟹B) ⊢ (∀xAx)⟹B the semantic demonstration looks, for a 'typical' structure with just one element t satisfying Ax[x\t] and all the other points p having Ax[x\p] false, the right hand side (rhs) gives ∀xAx as False, so rhs becomes  False ⟹B, which does not fix B, but as lhs gives B is true then rhs is true. In ∀x(Hx⟹P) this same structure makes P be true without having to invoke what is happening with  ((∃xHx)⟹P) (see my comment to my question above). ?

Comment: Ah, I think I get your problem now. Yes, if $P$ is a zero-place predicate whose truth value doesn't change under different terms substituted for $x$, then it can't be true for some $x$'s and false for others. First of all, by the semantics of $\to$, the cases where $Hx$ is false for all $x$es and those cases where $P$ is true (disregarding what happens to $Hx$) are unproblematic; the only thing that should *not* happen is that $P$ is false while for some (or all) $x$'es $Hx$ is true (like the scenario with $t$vs. $f$ you described, which would be contradictory). But precisely that scenario...

Comment: ... won't happen, because when $Hx$ is true for some $x$'es, then we have $\exists x$, and from $(\exists x Hx) \to P$ we know that then $P$ must true (and can not be false in the first place), so no contradiction can arise. Does this answer your question? (BTW, I would advise you to be more carful aobut $\vdash$ vs. $\vDash$, this can sometimes make a big difference. $\vdash$ is still purely about derivations in e.g. natural deduction. There is no "semantic demonstration" for $\vdash$. What you are talking about is $\vDash$, not $\vdash$.)